# Overflow:auto inside a flexbox behaves differently for children with display:block and display:flex

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

Children in flexbox if it has `display:flex`, they don't behave well with `overflow`.

Example I provided in codepen should be self explanatory: 
http://codepen.io/sanjay1909/pen/vGrJpG

I am not sure I understood flexbox correctly for flex values.

```
<div class="hbox">
 <div class="vbox resizingDiv">
  <div class="flexbox-item" style="flex-direction:column;overflow:auto">
   <div class="flexbox-inner">1</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">2</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">3</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">4</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">5</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">6</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">7</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">8</div>
   <div class="flexbox-inner">9</div>
  </div>
 <div class="flexbox-item ">flex-1</div>
 <div class="flexbox-item ">flex-1</div>
 <div class="flexbox-item ">flex-1</div>
</div>
<div class="vbox resizingDiv">
 <div class="flexbox-item" style="flex-direction:column;overflow:auto">
   <div class="block-inner">1</div>
  <div class="block-inner">2</div>
  <div class="block-inner">3</div>
  <div class="block-inner">4</div>
  <div class="block-inner">5</div>
  <div class="block-inner">6</div>
  <div class="block-inner">7</div>
  <div class="block-inner">8</div>
  <div class="block-inner">9</div>
 </div>
<div class="flexbox-item ">flex-1</div>
<div class="flexbox-item ">flex-1</div>
<div class="flexbox-item ">flex-1</div>
```

```
.hbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  background-color: #034;
  padding: 4px;
}
.vbox {
  display: flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 background-color: #0aa;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding: 4px;
}
.resizingDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
 }

.flexbox-item {
  display:flex;
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow:auto
 }

.flexbox-inner{
  display:flex;
  background-color: #aac;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}

.block-inner{
  background-color: #aac;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- Both groups of elements – `.flexbox-inner` and `.block-inner` – are flex items. Since they are children of a flex container, it doesn't matter if you give them `display:flex`, `display:block`, `display:table`, whatever. They are flex items and will accept flex properties.
- The problem you are having has nothing to do with the `overflow` property. If you remove the `overflow:auto` in your code, the stacking differential persists.
- The problem you are seeing exists in Chrome only. If you run your codepen in Firefox or IE11, you'll see that both sets of flex items stack the same. (They may render differently in another browser, but both overflow columns are identical in FF and IE11.)

[image]

- In Chrome, if you remove `display:flex` from the flex items, both columns will match.

So, *why does adding `display:flex` to the flex items in Chrome cause them to collapse?*

There's no clear answer for this and I found nothing in the [flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/). Considering it only happens in Chrome, it may just be a browser bug.

Comment: Thanks the screenshot explanation was very helpful